# Differences in base64_encode()

Tags: php, windows, active-directory

I am trying to write a PHP script that takes in a csv file and then creates an LDIFDE file for importing students into AD.

I have everything working BUT the password.

The problem seems to be with base64_encode() in PHP.

```
echo $password = '"Password1"';
echo "<br />";
echo $testPass = base64_decode("IgBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQAMQAiAA==");
echo "<br />";
echo base64_encode($password);
echo "<br />";
echo "IgBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQAMQAiAA==";
echo "<br />";
echo base64_encode($testPass);
```

The output is:

```
"Password1"
"Password1"
IlBhc3N3b3JkMSI=
IgBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQAMQAiAA==
IgBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQAMQAiAA==
```

I can't find the differnece between the "Password1"'s. Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? Once I can get my initial and encoded $password to match the encoded $testPass, I should be able to get this working right.

Comment: I just did a var_dump and got the following results
string '"Password1"' (length=11)
string '"�P�a�s�s�w�o�r�d�1�"�' (length=22)

I have no idea how to see what the � are. In the source, they come through as &#0;

Comment: btw try doing `echo 'chr'.ord($testpass[1]);` and tell me the result...

Comment: The string is UCS-2LE / UTF-16 Little Endian.  Posted an answer with how to convert to or from this, whichever is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to refer to your two base64 encoded strings as "the short string" and "the long string".

The long string seems to be the short string encoded into UTF16 Little Endian (or UCS-2LE).  Check out this hexdump of the decode of the long string:

```
          00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 - 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F  0123456789ABCDEF

00000000  22 00 50 00 61 00 73 00 - 73 00 77 00 6F 00 72 00  ".P.a.s.s.w.o.r.
00000010  64 00 31 00 22 00                                  d.1.".
```

As you can see, there is a null byte following each valid ASCII byte, which is where your differences are coming from.  The question is, do you want the long string or the short string?  Either way, check out [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://php.net/mb-convert-encoding) in the PHP manual to get you where you're going.

The encoding for the long string is "UCS-2LE"; the encoding for the short string will be something like "ISO-8859-1" or "cp1252".  Put these in the "from" and "to" arguments according to which one you are trying to produce.

#### Edit - Required calls

I posted this in the comments, but for ease of reference, I'm including it here.  In order to get the long string, call `mb_convert_encoding()` with 'UCS-2LE' as the second argument.  Example:

```
$password = '"Password1"';
echo base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding($password, 'UCS-2LE'));
```

Produces:

```
IgBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByAGQAMQAiAA==
```

Comment: I want the long string, from the documentation I have found. Let me look into this a little bit and get back to you. 
Thanks!

Comment: If you want the long string, then you'll need to do something like this:  `$some_string = base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding($original_string, 'UCS-2LE'));`  EDIT: Confirmed

Comment: Perfect. That was it and the mb_convert_encoding() did the trick. Thank you very much!